# Recompute a 3d vector field in a set of isosurfaces

Tags: graphics, visualization, data-visualization, gnuplot

I working on program (fortran90), which computes an magnetic field of some static set of wires with electric current. Its output is a magnetic field vectors in many points as file with columns "x,y,z,v_x,v_y,v_z). I able to plot this with gnuplot, e.g.:

[image: Single Vertical Wire]

But now I want to rewrite program to output isosurfaces (surfaces at which modulus of magnetic field vector is constant), like this (it is found in internet and don't correspond to first image)

[image: Some isosurface example]

Can I do this as second program or with using utility, which will convert my file with 6 columns into ... something format which can be drawn as surface set. Another way of doing this, as I think, is to rewrite first program to compute isosurface directly. Please, recommend me which way is better and how actually I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) can do it easily. It is cross-platform GPL plotting library which have Fortran interface too. Here you can use a sequential call of [vector fields](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_93.html#Vect-3D-sample) and [isosurface](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_92.html#Surf3-sample) plotting.

Comment: i think, mathgl will not interpolate my vector field counts into the isosurface equations. I don't see such usage in the linked examples. My task is to convert from vector field into isosurfaces of vector modulus.

Comment: Why not? Just create new array d=sqrt(v_x*v_x+v_y*v_y+v_z*v_z) and plot isosurfaces for it. At this, you can draw vector field too. Or do you want to draw vectors from points at isosurface(s)? This case is a bit more complex but can be done too. You can e-mail me for details.